# Unity: Unexpected Force after attaching rigid body

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, rigid-bodies

For some reason, when I attach a rigidbody to my actor, I discover an unexpected force. The game transitions from the first image to the second image without me or any script doing anything.

[image]

[image]

Perhaps of note is that in the first image, the transformation details are: Rotation: -90.00001, 0, 90 Position: -1.57, 0, 3 In the second image, the transformation details are: Rotation: -90.00001, 89.76601, -0.023 Position: -2.191998, 0.8199221, 3.375493

Comment: Make sure that your object is not touching the floor before adding the rigidbody. So, move your object up manually then add the rigidbody. Also, are you rotating/moving this object from script?

Comment: I found the error was that the mesh collision was colliding with itself. (didn't even know this was possible).